# To anyone who has made an app in the past month, how long

Tags: iphone

How long did you wait to get an app reviewed and put up on the app store. I have waited about 11 days now and it I am still waiting for review. So does it really take this long. I am kind of getting frustrated here. Any ways, how long does it take for you to get an app reviewed as of lately? Also, is it ok if your support site is a twitter or Facebook account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Between 3 and 14 days on average. Some releases take as long as 20 days and in really rare cases I have heard of apps taking multiple months to release. but Long time since I heard that.

I usually experience a week or week and a half.

Comment: Yeah if they don't review it in the next 3 days I am going to start raising some questions that is for sure. It isn't even christmas time yet and it is almost 2 weeks and still haven't enter in review. I swear apple needs to invest some money to make the review process go faster. They are worth over 600 billion dollars for god sakes.